# React Native - Get data from SQLite and pass this data to Picker Component

Tags: database, sqlite, react-native, components, picker

How to get data from SQLite database and pass this data to Picker Component with values and labels?

Comment: This is very general question!

Comment: Hello, Reza! Please, can you show me example?

Comment: you should ask one question at a time: getting data from SQLite and passing it to some component are different stories. Also show what you have tried: please keep in mind SO is Q&A, not a free coding service. Consult also https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: @YakovL Okey, now here is my code: https://imgur.com/a/betavou. I have getAllWorkers method and I pass all data from this method in Flatlist. How I can pass data from method to Picker Select? Please, show me example :)

Comment: ok, that's a start. Please include the code into your post as text (code), not as image

Comment: in case you still need some help and not sure why the code as text is important, you may want to read https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/3995261

Answer (score 0):

The question is so general, so I will answer generally. To get data from SQLite you can install this package on your react native project:

https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-sqlite-storage

Then you can use this pass your data in item section of this nice component:

https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-picker-select
Just follow the instructions for installing and configurations. 
To passing the data to the picker it is enough to put your data in the state and convert to to the proper way. To convert you can use following code and put it in the place that you retire the data:

```
 var myMatrix=[];
    yourRetriveData.map(function (item, ) {
       // console.log ("item [yourRetriveData.map]", item);

        obj= {
          "label": item.X,
          "value": item.Y,

        };

          myMatrix.push(obj);

      });
      that.setState({dataForPicker: myMatrix });
```

Instead of X and Y you can put your proper felids. Then in the picker you need this:

```
 {!this.state.dataForPicker ?
                <ActivityIndicator size="small" color="#fff" />:<RNPickerSelect
                placeholder={{
                    label: this.state.label,
                    value: this.state.value,
                }}
                items={this.state.data}
                onValueChange={(value, index) => {
                  this._handleItemPicked(value, index)
                }}
                placeholderTextColor={"#FFF"}
                placeholderTextColor={'rgba(255,255,255,1)'}
                value={this.props.value}
                style={{ ...pickerSelectStyles }}
                hideIcon={true}
              />}
```

I hope I could help.

Comment: I already use https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-sqlite-storage. But I have array of workers (Data) and I want to pass this data to Select Picker dynamically

Comment: @JackDaniels: So why you are asking such a general question!!!!?? You have to ask that part that you need.

Comment: @JackDaniels: Please provide your code and make a clear question. Thanks in advance.

Comment: This is my code for get all workers from database (SQLite) https://imgur.com/a/betavou. So I want to pass this data (all workers - for example worker_fname, worker_sname, worker_lname) to picker. How?

Comment: @JackDaniels: Thanks, Now it is better. I have updated my code.

Comment: @JackDaniels: Is it working? If yes, please mark this answer as a correct answer. Thanks

Comment: I don't know and I want  to get data with SQLite not with variables (matrix) and etc...

Comment: Can you show me image of all your code with correct answer and with SQLIte database and pass data from sqlite to select picker